# Is there a way to "expand" the Filter List in Lightning / Lightning App Builder?

Tags: apex, page-layout, lightning-apps, related-list

I am trying to make the UX more user friendly, and I would like to leverage OOTB List Views or Filter List on a page layout but can't seem to find a way to "expand" the list view / Filter List, what I mean but that is, spread out the data across the page, as opposed to bunched up unwrapped text like it would be displayed on Salesforce 1 or another mobile app. Is there any way to accomplish this declaratively?

[image]

Comment: The only way i see this happen the way you want it is to create lightning component and remove the related list section and rebuild as per your need. Will let others to answer in case they do see a better option to just customize related lists. As far as I know this is one of the limitations, you cannot customize related lists in lightning

Comment: Thanks Rao, I will look into building a component and rebuilding it.